# NextAuth Nextjs13 always calling localhost on Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

I created a simple project to test NextAuth and it works well on localhost.
When I deploy to Vercel, access api/auth/signin and try to login, it tries to call localhost:3000 credentials instead of the Vercel server.

I tried to set the env variable NEXTAUTH_URL on my localhost as google.com just to test, and it works, it redirects me to google.com when using signin.
But on Vercel no matter what NEXTAUTH_URL I try, it always tries to call localhost:3000.
(Other env variables on Vercel work, like my database)
I'm using Next.js 13 with the app directory

[image: NEXTAUTH_URL Vercel google.com]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
It is a problem with the pull request that I was using for NextAuth, that adds support to run NextAuth on the app directory, but apparently it has that problem on Vercel.
Will post there.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with `next-auth@4.22.0` and Route Handler support.
When deployed on Vercel, NextAuth is detecting host from headers `x-forwarded-host` and skipping NEXTAUTH_URL. But with Next 13 Route Handler, we have to use a new `headers()` method to read from request, which not used by NextAuth.
I opened a PR to fix this, waiting to be reviewed : https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/7220

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check your google cloud console credentials of your Oauth client.[image]

You need to add your custom URL there.